# How do I customize the values in this dropdown table for datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using datatables for my project and it works great. However I am not able to firgure out how to customize the filter dropdown values. Reason - some of the values are too long for example "Financial Controller abcdef tedfdffgg". I would like it to say just "Financial Controller" instead. Please see my code below. Thanks

Here is what I have. Link to the code - https://live.datatables.net/xocipofo/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer more information</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller abcdef tedfdffgg</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
const person = [{name:'Ashton Cox',position:'Technical Author',office:'San Francisco'},{name:'Brielle Williamson',position:'Integration Specialist',office:'New York'},{name:'Cedric Kelly',position:'Javascript Developer',office:'Edinburgh'}];
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
responsive: true,
searching: true
});
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
table.columns(0).search( this.value ).draw();
let myname = this.value;
let myoffice, myposition;
$.each(person,function(key, val) {
    if(val.name == myname) {
    myoffice = val.office;
    myposition = val.position;
  }
});
$('#dropdown2 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myposition) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
$('#dropdown3 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myoffice) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
});
$('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
let myposition = this.value;
let myoffice, myname;
$.each(person,function(key, val) {
    if(val.position == myposition) {
    myname = val.name;
    myoffice = val.office;
  }
});
$('#dropdown1 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myname) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
$('#dropdown3 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myoffice) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
} );
$('#dropdown3').on('change', function () {
table.columns(2).search( this.value ).draw();
let myoffice = this.value;
let myposition, myname;
$.each(person,function(key, val) {
    if(val.office == myoffice) {
    myname = val.name;
    myposition = val.position;
  }
});
$('#dropdown1 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myname) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
$('#dropdown2 option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() !== myposition) {
    $(this).attr('disabled','');
  }
});
} );

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code

```
 select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' );
```

is where it makes the drop down list.

The first d is where it sets what is searched for the second is here it changes the display -- so if you change it to

```
 select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">new: '+d+'</option>' );
```

every option will have a new before it.

similarly if you change it to

```
 select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d.substring(0,10)+'</option>' );
```

You will only get the first 10 characters in the display

https://live.datatables.net/pelodice/1